# Initialize a friend array in main form, VB

Tags: vb.net, arrays, windows-forms-designer, friend

I am working on a VB Windows Form and I have a question here about initialize an array (friend variable)

I have a `BookInfo` class as following:

```
Public Class BookInfoForm
  Friend _books() As BookInfo
  ...
EndClass
```

And in my main form, I want to initialize this `_books` array to be size 4.

What I have tried was:

```
_bookInfoForm._books(4) = New BookInfo
```

But this didn't work and it thrown an exception says

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I am wondering how I can have the array initialized to size 4. Anyone can help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to initialize your BookInfoForm class, then use `Redim` to resize your array

```
Dim BookInfo As New BookInfoForm
Redim BookInfo._books(4)
```

The `Redim` could resize your array but also clear all data in the array, if you want to keep those data while resizing your array, then you need to use `Preserve` after `Redim`

```
Redim Preserve BookInfo._books(4)
```

Comment: The argument to ReDim is the last index, not the size. "Redim BookInfo._books(4)" will make the array 5 elements long, not 4. From MSDN, [ReDim Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): "The upper bound is the highest possible value for that subscript, not the length of the dimension (which is the upper bound plus one)."